# Is it actually possible to pause Azure Synapse Analytics Dedidicated SQL Pool After a Period of Activity - Similar to Databricks

Tags: azure-synapse

Can someone let me know if its actually possible to pause Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Dedicated Pool after a period of activity?

I know its possible to shut down VMs in Spark Clusters after a period of inactivity.

Microsoft have provided the following link on how to automate the pause / resume of SQL Dedicated Pool.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/how-to-pause-resume-pipelines

But that link doesn't appear to answer the question pausing after a period of inactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by running monitoring queries in the SQL pool using script activity or stored procedure activity.

[image: image1]

Use the following query in Script activity :

```
select count(*) as queriesRunning from sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests WHERE status='Running' and session_id <> session_id();

SELECT min(DATEDIFF (mi, end_compile_time, getutcdate())) as minutesPassed FROM sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests WHERE session_id <> session_id()
```

[image: image2]

Use the below expression in If condition block:

```
@and(equals(activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].queriesRunning,0),greaterOrEquals(activity('Script1').output.resultSets[3].rows[0].minutesPassed,2))
```

Case 1: When query is running :

```
equals(activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].queriesRunning,0 will result in false
```

[image: gif1]

Case 2: When there is no active query but minutes passed is < 2:
[image: egif2]

Case 3: When there is no active query and minutes passed is >=2:
[image: gif3]

Comment: This is a game changer. I can't believe Microsift hasn't published this fix in the past. So many projects I've been involved with have been either postponed or rejected because there was no way of shutting down due to inactivity. Amazing. Thank you

Comment: is it possible to spin up a dedicated pool automatically? For example, to spin up a dedicated SQL server you have to click resume.